# Library for calculating GTIN from EAN-13 barcode

Tags: c#, xml, barcode

I am creating an XML from a backend that is supposed to be fed into a GDSN datapool. The company has a very old backend which only has their own PLU number and barcode attached to every item. What I know is that (at least here in Iceland) most GTIN are the EAN-13 barcode with a padded 0 at the front although this is not always the case. Do you know of a library that could check if a GTIN is correct i.e. would calculate the check digit?

I am using a windows form and am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to validate what you want to do:
https://www.gs1.org/services/check-digit-calculator

Then you have 2 possibilities for GTIN since it must be 14 digits long.

- The case you described, then you pad a 0 on the left
- A GTIN with right length is provided directly (which is possible and left digit will not be 0)

Here is a quick example on how you can check this, based on the fact you know the gtin string only contains digits:

```
    public Boolean ValidateGTIN(string gtin)
    {
        string tmpGTIN = gtin;
        if (tmpGTIN.Length < 13)
        {
            Console.Write("GTIN code is invalid (should be at least 13 digits long)");
            return false;
        }
        else if (tmpGTIN.Length == 13)
        {
            tmpGTIN = "0" + gtin;
        }
        // Now that you have a GTIN with 14 digits, you can check the checksum
        Boolean IsValid = false;
        int Sum = 0;
        int EvenSum = 0;
        int CurrentDigit = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos <= 12; ++pos)
        {                
            Int32.TryParse(tmpGTIN[pos].ToString(), out CurrentDigit);
            if (pos % 2 == 0)
            {                    
                EvenSum += CurrentDigit;
            }                    
            else
            {
                Sum += CurrentDigit;
            }                    
        }
        Sum += 3 * EvenSum;
        Int32.TryParse(tmpGTIN[13].ToString(), out CurrentDigit);
        IsValid = ((10 - (Sum % 10)) % 10) == CurrentDigit;
        if (!IsValid)
        {
            Console.Write("GTIN code is invalid (wrong checksum)");
        }
        return IsValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. This is almost there. I would like to take it a step further - I am going to copy your code and add a little:

```
//First create a function only for validating
//This is your code to almost all - variable names change  
public Boolean validateGTIN(string gtin)
    {
        Boolean IsValid = false;
        int Sum = 0;
        int EvenSum = 0;
        int CurrentDigit = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos <= 12; ++pos)
        {                
            Int32.TryParse(gtin[pos].ToString(), out CurrentDigit);
            if (pos % 2 == 0)
            {                    
                EvenSum += CurrentDigit;
            }                    
            else
            {
                Sum += CurrentDigit;
            }                    
        }
        Sum += 3 * EvenSum;
        Int32.TryParse(GTIN[13].ToString(), out CurrentDigit);
        IsValid = ((10 - (Sum % 10)) % 10) == CurrentDigit;
        if (!IsValid)
        {
            Console.Write("GTIN code is invalid (wrong checksum)");
        }
        return IsValid;
    }
//Here we change quite a bit to accommodate for edge cases:
//We return a string which is the GTIN fully formed or we throw and exception.
public String createGTIN(string bcFromBackend)
    {
        string barcodeStr = bcFromBackend;
//Here we check if the barcode supplied has fewer than 13 digits
        if (barcodeStr.Length < 13)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Barcode not an EAN-13 
            barcode");
        }
        //If the barcode is of length 13 we start feeding the value with a padded 0 
        //into our validate fuction if it returns false then we pad with 1 and so on
        //until we get to 9. It then throws an error if not valid  
        else if (barcodeStr.Length == 13)
        {
            if(validateGTIN("0"+ barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "0" + barcodeStr;
            } 
            else if(validateGTIN("1" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "1" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("2" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "2" + barcodeStr;
            }  
            else if(validateGTIN("3" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "3" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("4" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "4" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("4" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "4" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("5" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "5" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("6" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "6" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("7" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "7" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("8" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "8" + barcodeStr;
            }
            else if(validateGTIN("9" + barcodeStr))
            {
                 return "9" + barcodeStr;
            } else {
                 throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Unable to create valid 
                 GTIN from given barcode")
            }
        }
        //Lastly if the barcode is of length 14 we try with this value. Else throw 
        //error
        else if(barcodeStr.Length == 14)
        {
            if(validateGTIN(barcodeStr)
            {
                 return barcodeStr;
            }
            else
            {
                 throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Unable to create valid 
                 GTIN from given barcode");
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I have not sent the code through testing as I don't have my IDE on my current computer installed. Is

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure since I didn't checked GS1 for some time, but I think you should always pad with a 0 when the user purposely provide a 13 digit code. You should not try all the other ones...

Comment: Anyway, if you can to accept my answer or yours it will permit to mark this question as answered